# what does and. (and followed by dot) in sql server mean?

Tags: sql-server-2000

We are migrating our database to new SQL server version from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2016. Some stored procedures use old syntaxes which represents different clauses in new SQL version. For eg:

for left joins, old server uses something like the below.

```
select 1 from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.ID *= t2.ID
```

New version of SQL would be

```
select 1 from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Similarly, I am looking for a corresponding new syntax for the below code used in SQL server 2000

```
select 1 from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on (t1.Field1 = t2.Field1 and. t1.Field2 = t2.Field2)
```

The above query executes without error in 2000 server but in 2016 version it shows error in the place where `and.` is mentioned.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not really a new syntax, it just looks weird. "and. t1.field2" is same as "and .t1.field2"
.t1.field2 is a three-part name where database name is ommited, so it's same as t1.field2